# Reorder javascript object based on specific key values

Tags: javascript, json, object, refactoring

Here's my dataset

```
var myData = [
  {
    key: 'female', 
    value: 1000
  },
  {
    key: 'male', 
    value: 2000
  },
  {
    key: 'unknown', 
    value: 150
  }
];
```

I want to reorder these objects from 'female --> male --> unknown' to 'male --> female --> unknown'.

My original solution was to do like so:

```
var newAudienceArray = [];

for (var x = 0; x < myData.length; x++){
  if (myData[x].key == 'male'){
    newAudienceArray.push(myData[x]);
  }
}

for (var x = 0; x < myData.length; x++){
  if (myData[x].key == 'female'){
    newAudienceArray.push(myData[x]);
  }
}

for (var x = 0; x < myData.length; x++){
  if (myData[x].key == 'unknown'){
    newAudienceArray.push(myData[x]);
  }
}
```

This seems extremely verbose. Is there a more concise solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Array.prototype.sort method:

```
myData.sort(function (index, data) { 
    return data.key == 'male' ? 2 : data.key == 'female' ? 1 : 0 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create one object with `key`'s value as key and position you want that element to have in sorted array as value. And then you can use `sort()` method to sort by that object.

```js
var myData = [{"key":"female","value":1000},{"key":"male","value":2000},{"key":"unknown","value":150}]

var sortBy = {
  male: 1,
  female: 2,
  unknown: 3
}

var result = myData.sort(function(a, b) {
  return sortBy[a.key] - sortBy[b.key]
})

console.log(result)
```